# New Shimano TX55 Not Shifting

Tags: derailleur

[image: View of the derailleur cable]

I am having a problem with my rear derailleur. I installed as per instructions, adjusting the H and L limits to what I believe is proper. The problem I am having is that when I am in 7th gear, shifting down doesn't actually shift. The cable tightens, but it just pulls the derailleur back instead of sideways along to the next gear. I have tried both tightening and loosening the cable in various amounts. I also noticed that I can push the derailleur from side to side (as if it were changing gears) while the cable remains at the same tension.

As this is the first derailleur that I have installed myself, I really have no idea whats wrong. Did I install it wrong? Is it broken? I'd appreciate any help.

*EDIT* Added a newer video that hopefully shows the problem better.

[Here's a video of the problem](https://youtu.be/_appFdHOOv0)

Comment: you have something hooked up wrong, but a small, dimly lit video isn't enough to say what. Can you take a couple of clear photos of where the cable attaches to the derailleur please?

Comment: I've added an image of the rear derailleur. The cable goes into the housing, around the pulley, through the second guide, and into the lock bolt. Let me know if you need more photos, and thanks for the help!

Comment: Is the cable housing there (between the chain stay cable guide / stop and the derailer? I think I see it, but it is hard to be positive.

Comment: (note that the bike is upside down in that photo)

Comment: The cable housing is on the cable between the derailleur and the cable guide on the bike frame. Is that the part you meant, dlu?

Comment: I have changed the video link to a new video that hopefully shows the problem better.

Comment: Yes. That's what I was wondering about.

Comment: Your housing looks to be a bit too short, and not get inside the cable guide on the frame (24-27sec in your video. the light isn't well there so it's hard to say). Anyway, your derailleur seems to move enough for change gears, so i assume it's broken.

Comment: I believe, by that video, you've not put the mech hanger on properly. It also appears your jockey wheel is MILES away from where it should be. Are you able to force the deraileur along the cogs by hand while pushing the pedals around? Can the deraileur even pivot by their bolts? Has the mech hanger been put on properly? Has the cable been made the correct length? (The outer cable housing)  

I would need some more photos and I also ask you to check if it's correct by photo guides on the internet, such as a technical diagram of where the hanger should be in relation to the mech itself. GL!

Comment: Another thing I've just noticed is that you seem to be missing a barrel adjuster; Does this mech come with one or has it become lost? Again, Good luck!

Comment: Once the image is rotated the right way up it's a bit easier to see what's happening IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help! I had a friend take a look at it in person. Turn out the cable housing between the frame and the derailleur was too short. The derailleur was cocking back until it caught the cable housing, then working as normal. After a replacement with longer housing, the bike is now working perfectly.

Thanks again to all who helped!